# Multi Database with same table name in flask_sqlalchemy

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have multi databases, like `order_db1`、`order_db2`、`order_db3`,

but they all have table `order`, but data in `order_db1.order` is different from `order_db2.order`,

`order_db1.order`

| id | amount|

| 1| 100|

`order_db2.order`

| id | amount|

| 1| 200|

how can I access multi database with same table name in flask_sqlalchemy ？

I tried like this，use `SQLALCHEMY_BINDS`：

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from flask import Flask

from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import logging


class Application(Flask):
    def __init__(self, import_name):
        super(Application, self).__init__(import_name)

app = Application(__name__)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_BINDS'] = {
'order_db1': 'mysql://%s:%s@%s/order_db1' % (mysql_user, quote_plus(mysql_pwd),mysql_host),
'order_db2': 'mysql://%s:%s@%s/order_db2' % (mysql_user, quote_plus(mysql_pwd),mysql_host),
}
```

```
class Order1(db.model):
    __bind_key__ = 'order_db1'
    __tablename__ = 'order'
    id = db.colum(db.Interger)
    amount = db.colum(db.Interger)

class Order2(db.model):
    __bind_key__ = 'order_db2'
    __tablename__ = 'order'
    id = db.colum(db.Interger)
    amount = db.colum(db.Interger)

q1=Order1.query.get(1)
q2=Order2.query.get(1)
```

It told me :

'sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Table 'order' is already defined for this MetaData instance.  Specify 'extend_existing=True' to redefine options and columns on an existing Table object.'

But if I add `__table_args = {'extend_existing': True}`

```
class Order1(db.model):
    __bind_key__ = 'order_db1'
    __tablename__ = 'order'
    __table_args = {'extend_existing': True}

    id = db.colum(db.Interger)
    amount = db.colum(db.Interger)


class Order2(db.model):
    __bind_key__ = 'order_db2'
    __tablename__ = 'order'
    __table_args = {'extend_existing': True}

    id = db.colum(db.Interger)
    amount = db.colum(db.Interger)

q1=Order1.query.get(1)
q2=Order2.query.get(1)
```

the data in `q1` is the same with `q2`, means id=1,amount=200

I want it like :

q1: id=1, amount=100

q2: id=1, amount=200

Comment: Did you declare the binds as described in the [documentation](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/binds/). If yes, please provide the code.

Comment: yes, I declare it and I have updated my question with  the  code

Comment: There are known issues with binds and identical table names. See this [discussion](https://github.com/pallets/flask-sqlalchemy/pull/222) and this possible [workaround](https://github.com/pallets/flask-sqlalchemy/issues/773).

Answer (score 0):

There are known issues with binds and identical table names. See this [discussion](https://github.com/pallets/flask-sqlalchemy/pull/222) and this possible [workaround](https://github.com/pallets/flask-sqlalchemy/issues/773).

An alternative workaround is to use two `Sqlalchemy` instances, which may be or not acceptable for your use case. See single file example using SQLite.

```
import random
from flask import Flask, render_template_string
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_BINDS'] = {
    'order_db1': 'sqlite:///order_db1.sqlite',
    'order_db2': 'sqlite:///order_db2.sqlite',
}

db1 = SQLAlchemy(app)
db2 = SQLAlchemy(app)


class Order1(db1.Model):
    __bind_key__ = 'order_db1'
    __tablename__ = 'order'

    id = db1.Column(db1.Integer, primary_key=True)
    amount = db1.Column(db1.Integer)


class Order2(db2.Model):
    __bind_key__ = 'order_db2'
    __tablename__ = 'order'

    id = db2.Column(db2.Integer, primary_key=True)
    amount = db2.Column(db2.Integer)


_html_template = '''
        <p>Order 1 count:{{order_1_count}}</p>
        <p>Order 2 count:{{order_2_count}}</p>
    '''


@app.route('/')
def index():
    order_1_count = Order1.query.count()
    order_2_count = Order2.query.count()

    return render_template_string(_html_template, order_1_count=order_1_count, order_2_count=order_2_count)


@app.before_first_request
def build_sample_db():

    db1.drop_all()
    db2.drop_all()

    db1.create_all()
    db2.create_all()

    # Create 100 records in db1
    db1.session.add_all([Order1(amount=random.randint(0, 100)) for _ in enumerate(range(0, 100))])
    db1.session.commit()

    # Create 1000 records in db1
    db2.session.add_all([Order2(amount=random.randint(1000, 10000)) for _ in enumerate(range(0, 1000))])
    db2.session.commit()

    return app


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```